# How reliable is Android camera2 CameraCharacteristics API for sensor size?

Tags: android, android-sensors, android-camera2

I'm trying to get/compute the FOV for devices's cameras using `camera2` API my code at the bottom).

On my attempt on a Galaxy S7 :

- the given sensor size is 3.2mm x 2.4mm (using `SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE`).
- In this case, my computed HFOV is 41.7° (focal length given is 4.2mm) which I proved wrong by experimentation.
- Various spec doc mention a 1/2.5" sensor size (5.76mm x 4.29mm according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_sensor_format)) - which would give me a HFOV of 68.9°, closer to my experiments.
- the values in `CameraCharacteristics` seem wrong.

The same queries and experiments on a Samsung Galaxy A3-2016 are more conclusive, the calculated HFOV seems to match the experimental one.

Has anyone experience or data to share about the reliability of `CameraCharacteristics` readings ?

---

The code I used to query `CameraCharacteristics` ::

```
CameraCharacteristics characteristics = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraID);
if (characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING) == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT)
    continue;

int support = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL);
if( support == CameraMetadata.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LEGACY )
    Log.d("mr", "Camera " + cameraID + " has LEGACY Camera2 support");
else if( support == CameraMetadata.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_LIMITED )
    Log.d("mr", "Camera " + cameraID + " has LIMITED Camera2 support");
else if( support == CameraMetadata.INFO_SUPPORTED_HARDWARE_LEVEL_FULL )
    Log.d("mr", "Camera " + cameraID + " has FULL Camera2 support");
else
    Log.d("mr", "Camera " + cameraID + " has unknown Camera2 support?!");

// voir http://myandroidarchive.tistory.com/5 pour le query android
// voir http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/lens/ pour les maths
// include every focal length supported by the camera device, in ascending order.
float[] focalLengths = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_INFO_AVAILABLE_FOCAL_LENGTHS);
SizeF sensorSize = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_INFO_PHYSICAL_SIZE);

float w = 0.5f * sensorSize.getWidth();
float h = 0.5f * sensorSize.getHeight();
Log.d("mr", "Camera " + cameraID + " has sensorSize == " + Float.toString(2.0f*w) + ", " + Float.toString(2.0f*h));
for (int focusId=0; focusId<focalLengths.length; focusId++) {
    float focalLength = focalLengths[focusId];
    float horizonalAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(2 * Math.atan(w / focalLength));
    float verticalAngle = (float) Math.toDegrees(2 * Math.atan(h / focalLength));
    Log.d("mr", "Camera " + cameraID + "/f" + focusId + " has focalLength == " + Float.toString(focalLength));
    Log.d("mr", "  * horizonalAngle == " + Float.toString(horizonalAngle));
    Log.d("mr", "  * verticalAngle == " + Float.toString(verticalAngle));
}
```

Comment: I remember in legacy camera to calculate field of view you had to start preview first because if you get those values before starting the camera preview then they can be different from values after starting preview, mb the same for camera2, but in when I was calculating field of view using legacy camera it was correct, so accuracy is good

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Developer of Scanbot here (aka I worked with camera enough).

From my experience nothing about Camera API can be reliable mostly because this API is a relatively thin layer upon hardware and vendor specific camera driver. In other words, output of API will depend on what vendor decided to put there and is not (unlike the rest of the Android SDK) governed by Google.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, do you happen to know a simple app that displays all the CameraCharacteristics values for a device ?

Comment: No, never searched for one

Comment: Yes this is annoying. On my Xiaomi Mi A2 Lite the` LENS_FACING_BACK` constant results in the camera session starting from the _front_ facing camera. And `LENS_FACING_FRONT` from the back. The `FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE` only returns _available_ for the supposed _back_ camera, so android thinks it's right.